# HTML form within another form

Tags: php

I am new to html, I would be really glad if you can help me with this.

I have a web page where there is a list and some other text inputs and buttons.  This option list can be populated by clicking the "add" button in the page, this add button is to direct to another page and in that page there are some chekboxes, those which are checked are loaded back to the main page,(where I have the list) .

At the end data in the main page needs to be loaded to the database, (what is in the list and in the text inputs).

Since I'm new I just know little about php and html, I thought I should have a form within a another form(form to "add items", form to load to the database) and it is not possible in html.  Can anyone suggest the best way to do this?  Do I need to use javascript?

Comment: Would be more helpful if you'd convert those words to codes..

Answer (score 1):

Why can't the extra inputs (the ones that would be in the second form) be part of the first form? I think the question will become clearer if you post a sample form so we can see the relationship between the two forms.

But overall, since you're ultimately only submitting one form, then maybe all the inputs belong together. If what you're calling the second form isn't supposed to be visible right away, you can still have it be part of the same form, but only reveal it when needed.

Again, some sample data would help to understand the exact context of your question.

Comment: I guess what I meant to say was what do these two forms look like? What information do they request?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nkuGo.png

This is what i want,(as in the picture) Option list gets updated from another php page

Answer (score 1):

in php if you use input name="somename[]"
for a  number of input elems
you will get an array in $_POST['somename'] and access all the values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , what i really need to know is how to retrieve data from another web page with out submitting the whole form..
http://i.stack.imgur.com/nkuGo.png 
This is how it looks. The whole form is to insert data in to the database, and sub form is to get the vales to the option list (using add button) by directing to another php page.

Comment: what do you mean exactly? You can save the data of the array some where and retrieve it when you get back to the original page!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after - if I understand you correctly - is ajax. Ajax allows you to asynchronously send data to/from another script without leaving the current page. This is accomplished using JavaScript. In your case I think what you need to do is set an onclick event in JavaScript to a button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascriptFunction()">
```

You can read more about ajax here:
http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajaxform.php